# show X,Y Coordinate shapefile in google map

Tags: api, google-maps

I wanna show this Shapefile data that extracted from SHP file in google map API :

DATA :Array
(
    [Id] => 0
    [area] => 164.914
    [PARCID] =>
    [deleted] => 0
)
SHAPE :Array
(
    [xmin] => 539544.25
    [ymin] => 3947728.5
    [xmax] => 539559.4375
    [ymax] => 3947745.75
    [numparts] => 1
    [numpoints] => 15
    [parts] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [points] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [x] => 539546
                                    [y] => 3947731.75
                                )

```
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539544.25
                                [y] => 3947732
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539545.5
                                [y] => 3947736.5
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539546.375
                                [y] => 3947739.5
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539546.8125
                                [y] => 3947741
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539548.1875
                                [y] => 3947745.75
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539556
                                [y] => 3947743
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539556.1875
                                [y] => 3947743.5
                            )

                        [8] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539559.4375
                                [y] => 3947742.25
                            )

                        [9] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539557.8125
                                [y] => 3947737
                            )

                        [10] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539556.75
                                [y] => 3947733
                            )

                        [11] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539555.375
                                [y] => 3947728.5
                            )

                        [12] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539554.5
                                [y] => 3947728.75
                            )

                        [13] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539549.3125
                                [y] => 3947730.75
                            )

                        [14] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 539546
                                [y] => 3947731.75
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

but when I check it get LATLNG coordinate, anyone can help to put these X,Y data on google map data !!!!

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure what you want to use is JSON to parse it and send it to Google Maps.  First you will need to format your numbers into actual latitude longitude coordinates.  Here is how to use JSON to parse it: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/jsondevguide.html

Alternately, I am not sure what you are trying to do with the data, but you could send it via a query string. (ex. http://maps.google.com/maps?q=52.961875,55.003296).